# Parameters from URL separate

Tags: php, url

i have got an URL:

http://website.example/script.php?timestamp=2014-10-31T16%3A12%3A57&sms=PM+000+name

and i want to catch values separated by '+'
if there is ability to add to array or what:

```
array sms[
  array_value1 = PM
    array_value2 = 000
      array_value3 = name]
```

and then take value like

```
$name1 = $array_value3;
```

which will be "name"

Also if it would be done from this:

$timestamp = "2014-10-31**T**16**%3A**12**%3A**57";

this:

```
$timestamp = "2014-10-31-16:12:37";
```

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close but i wanted right this:

```
$raw = $_GET["sms"];
list($type, $number, $user) = explode(" ", $raw, 3);
```

and `echo $user` would give result: name

Now need to do somethink with that time formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$foo = explode(' ', $_GET['sms']); // array('PM','000','name')
```

That what you're after? The `+` is just an encoding for a space (`%20`), so server-side you're looking at splitting it by spaces (though they would all fall under the same parameter).

Keep in mind if "name" turned into "name surname", you'll end up with a 4th array element containing "surname". (`Array('PM','000','name','surname')`)

Answer (score 0):

```
$url=urldecode("http://website.example/script.php?timestamp=2014-10-31T16%3A12%3A57&sms=PM+0+name");
$url=parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$url_split = explode('&', $url);
$timestamp=$url_split[0];
$sms=explode(' ', $url_split[1]);
```